# Moving average in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, average, rolling-average

I have a csv file with 3 columns and I want to get the moving average of 1 column.
I want to create a new column with the moving average.

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.read_csv('csv',usecols=['speed','col2', 'col3'])
df['MA'] = df.rolling( window=5, on='speed').mean
print(df)
```

It doesnt show me any column anymore. Only the Index and ... .

```
1   ...
2   ...
3   ...
3   ...
4   ...

[4 rows x 4 columns]
```

If I change to:

```
df= df.rolling(window=5, on='speed').mean
print(df)
```

It only returns me this:

```
<bound method Rolling.mean of Rolling [window=5,center=False,axis=0,on=speed]>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Missing `()` like `df['MA'] = df.rolling( window=5, on='speed').mean()`

Comment: I get an error now: ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1

Comment: It depends on the used columns. If I cahnge usecols to 'speed' only it works fine.

Answer (score 6):

Posting one more way.

```
     df['MA'] = df['speed'].rolling(window=5).mean()
```